# Google Sheets: Why is the first cell of my query repeating?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am compiling multiple sheets into one master sheet. The first four rows of the first sheet in my array are repeating in one cell instead of listing in separate cells. No matter which sheet I list first, the first four sells end up being in one cell. The second sheet listed does not have this problem. My data starts in the 5th row in column B.

This is the formula I'm using:

```
=QUERY({A!B5:U; B!B5:U},"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

[Table Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWATR.png)

Comment: Can you share a public copy of the sheet to see how do you have it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 3rd query parameter:

```
=QUERY({A!B5:U; B!B5:U}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```